# What is the Tseitin transformation of a single literal?

Tags: logic, satisfiability, conjunctive-normal-form

The wikipedia page for Tseitin transformation includes a nice example of the transform itself. In the example, it is implied that there is no need to create a fresh variable for a single literal (that is not negated).

What is the Tseitin transform of a single literal, e.g. A?

Is it just $A$?

Or is it $X_1 \land A$?

Or is it $X_1 \land (X_1∨¬A)∧(¬X_1∨A)$?

Comment: The transformation applies to complex formula. A single literal is already in CNF and DNF.